# Trying to get usercontrol to load the connection string available at MainWindow (WPF, C# related )

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, connection-string, dependency-properties

I was getting the blue squiggly line when I was trying to load the connection string from my usercontrol. I googled and found that we have to either created dependency property or bindings or include the (!.this.designmode) code in the application.

However, I googled and I tried the dependency property, it works, but I was still getting the squiggly line and an error as well - Connection string was not initialized. I then modified the code to call the method when the dependency property's event handler is called ( Not sure if I am doing the right thing ).

Would like to be advised on what is the proper way of calling the method that contains the reference to the connection string? I actually included it in the constructor right after the InitializeComponent() call which was leading to the error. I have now included it in the event handler, but is this the right way to do it ? The method's name is   GetDatafromReasons();

This is my usercontrol code.

```
   namespace BPSDesktopApp.Reasons
 {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainReasonsUC.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainReasonsUC : UserControl
{

    DataSet reason_ds = new DataSet("ReasonDataSet");
    DataTable reason_tbl = new DataTable("ReasonTable");
    List<SubReason> Reasons = new List<SubReason>();
    string connstringfromparent = " ";

    public class SubReason
    {
        public int ReasonId { get; set; }
        public string ReasonText { get; set; }

    }

    public MainReasonsUC()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateDatatable();
             //GetDatafromReasons();
            // ConvertDataTabletoList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.File, ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SetConnStringProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ConnString", typeof(string), typeof(MainReasonsUC), new
      PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(SetConnStringProp_Changed)));

    public string ConnString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SetConnStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SetConnStringProperty, value); }
    }


    private static void SetConnStringProp_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainReasonsUC mrusercontrol = d as MainReasonsUC;
        mrusercontrol.SetConnStringProp_Changed(e);
    }


    private void SetConnStringProp_Changed(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        label.Content = e.NewValue.ToString();
        connstringfromparent = e.NewValue.ToString();
        GetDatafromReasons();

    }







}
```

}

and this is my Main Window

```
    public partial class ReasonsWindow : Window
{
    string connstring1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["submittodb"].ToString();
    public ReasonsWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainReasons_UControl.ConnString = connstring1;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, there is a naming convention for the identifier field of a dependency property. It should be named `ConnStringProperty` for a property named `ConnString`. Besides that, you are right, you should handle a changed dependency property value in a PropertyChangedCallback that is registered with dependency property metadata.

Comment: As another note, you should prefer an explicit cast `(MainReasonsUC)d` over `d as MainReasonsUC` in the callback, because in (the unlikely) case that `d` is not a MainReasonsUC, you would correctly get an InvalidCastException instead of an incorrect NullReferenceException. In general, never use `as` without checking the result for `null`.

Comment: @Clemens..thanks for the reply. Really appreciate it. Will adhere to the naming convention.